# How do I setup a Polycom phone over internet connection sharing?

Tags: windows-7, windows, voip, ics, polycom

What are the *Internet Connection Sharing* settings that I need so that I can have my *Polycom phone* utilize my *wireless* connection?

The physical configuration is as follows:

- Computer accesses the internet over 'Wireless Network Connection'
- Polycom Phone is connected to the Computer over 'Local Area Connection'

Here are the physical configuration limitations:

- Router is located in another room of the house
- Polycom Phone must be near Computer for live meetings
- Computer room does not have CAT-5/6 outlet

These reasons are why I need to piggyback the Polycom Phone's internet access on the 'Wireless Network Connection'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that the *Polycom Phone* works over the internet and can register itself properly. To do this, connect it directly to the router or a wired connection and test it to make sure you can place a call. If you can, that means that the phone can register itself with the SIP provider and you can continue trying to setup it up over *Internet Connection Sharing* knowing that the phone works properly over your typical wired connection.

1. Right click on 'Wireless Network Connection'
2. Go to Properties
3. Go to Sharing tab
4. Check 'Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection
5. Select 'Local Area Connection'
6. Check 'Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet connection
7. Click on Settings button

Add these services for Polycom communications (Description - Port - Protocol):

- GAB - 3601 - TCP
- ILS - 1002 - TCP
- LDAP & ILS - 389 - TCP
- SIP - 53164 - UDP
- SIP - 5004 - TCP
- SIP - 5060 - TCP
- SIP - 5060 - UDP
- Telnet Server - 23 - TCP
- Time - 123 - UDP
- Secure Web Server (HTTPS) - 443 - TCP
- Web Server (HTTP) - 80 - TCP

Once that is complete the *Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)* should work and so should the Polycom Phone. If there are problems, download Wireshark and trace the packets that come through across 'Local Area Connection'. You will be able to see all the communication that the Polycom Phone makes over the internet.

Furthermore, you may have problems when the router's IP/DHCP server is setup on 192.168.1.1 and you may have to change it to 192.168.0.1.